# Unexpected behavior of coerce inside foldMap's callback

Tags: haskell, coerce

This code compiles:

```
import Data.List (isPrefixOf)
import Data.Monoid (Any(..))
import Data.Coerce

isRoot :: String -> Bool
isRoot path = getAny $ foldMap (coerce . isPrefixOf) ["src", "lib"] $ path
```

I'm using [`coerce`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html#v:coerce) as a shortcut for wrapping the final result of [`isPrefixOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:isPrefixOf) in [`Any`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Any).

This similar code doesn't compile (notice the lack of `.`):

```
isRoot :: String -> Bool
isRoot path = getAny $ foldMap (coerce isPrefixOf) ["src", "lib"] $ path
```

The error is:

```
* Couldn't match representation of type `a0' with that of `Char'
    arising from a use of `coerce'
* In the first argument of `foldMap', namely `(coerce isPrefixOf)'
  In the first argument of `($)', namely
    `foldMap (coerce isPrefixOf) ["src", "lib"]'
  In the second argument of `($)', namely
    `foldMap (coerce isPrefixOf) ["src", "lib"] $ path'
```

But my intuition was that it, too, should compile. After all, we know that the arguments of `isPrefixOf` will be `String`s, and that the result must be of type`Any`. There's no ambiguity. So `String -> String -> Bool` should be converted to `String -> String -> Any`. Why isn't it working?

Comment: Does that differ from `isRoot = or . sequence (map isPrefixOf ["src", "lib"])`  ? Just curious.

Comment: @jpmarinier It's equivalent. Although the code is a bit artificial, the focus of my question is the issue with `coerce`.

Comment: MVCE: `coerce id :: Int -> Int` produces the same problem, however `coerce (id :: Int -> Int) :: Int -> Int` does not. So there is some interaction with polymorphism.

Comment: @luqui Interesting. It's as if GHC couldn't reason "from the outside in" on an application of `coerce`, and doesn't conclude that the inner `id` could be made monomorphic from the fact that the result of the `coerce` is monomorphic. In the `foldMap` case, it seems a bit more surprising, because the type of the list's elements is fixed to `Char` by `["src", "lib"]`.

Comment: My guess is that `coerce isPrefixOf`, unlike `coerce . isPrefixOf`, can also affect the input of `isPrefixOf`. If we had `newtype CaseInsensitive = CI Char` with a custom `Eq` instance, then `coerce isPrefixOf` could mean `\x y -> coerce (isPrefixOf x y)` or `\x y -> coerce (isPrefixOf (map CI x) (map CI y))` which has a different semantics. Hence the code is ambiguous (?)

Comment: @danidiaz - Thanks. BTW it seems you get some sort of hints by making a “type hole”, that is you replace `coerce` by `_coerce` in the source code. Seems the compiler is led astray by the polymorphic nature of `isPrefixOf`. No idea why. If you use `(coerce (isPrefixOf :: String -> String -> Bool))`, it does typecheck. In similar fashion, if the `TypeApplications` GHC extension is enabled, using `(coerce (isPrefixOf @Char))` works fine too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with coercions.  It's just constraint solving in general.  Consider:

```
class Foo a b
instance Foo (String -> Bool) (String -> Any)
instance Foo (String -> String -> Bool) (String -> String -> Any)

foo :: Foo a b => a -> b
foo = undefined

bar :: String -> String -> Any
bar = foo . isPrefixOf

baz :: String -> String -> Any
baz = foo isPrefixOf
```

The definition of `bar` works fine; the definition of `baz` fails.

In `bar`, the type of `isPrefixOf` can be directly inferred as `String -> String -> Bool`, simply by unifying the type of `bar`s first argument (namely `String`) with the first argument type of `isPrefixOf`.

In `baz`, nothing whatsoever can be inferred about the type of `isPrefixOf` from the expression `foo isPrefixOf`.  The function `foo` could do anything to the type of `isPrefix` to get the resulting type `String -> String -> Any`.

Remember that constraints don't really influence type unification.  Unification occurs as if the constraints weren't there, and when unification is finished, the constraints are demanded.

Getting back to your original example, the following is a perfectly valid coercion, so the ambiguity is real:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

import Data.Char
import Data.List (isPrefixOf)
import Data.Monoid (Any(..))
import Data.Coerce

newtype CaselessChar = CaselessChar Char
instance Eq CaselessChar where CaselessChar x == CaselessChar y = toUpper x == toUpper y

isRoot :: String -> Bool
isRoot path = getAny $ foldMap (coerce (isPrefixOf @CaselessChar)) ["src", "lib"] $ path
```

Answer (score 3):

`isPrefix` has inferred type `[a] -> [a] -> Bool` (with a constraint `Eq a`) the expected type of `coerce isPrefix` there is `[Char] -> [Char] -> Any`, so you end up with a constraint `Coercible a Char`, but there is nothing that actually constrains `a` to be `Char`. In fact, it could be any newtype around `Char`, which might have a different `Eq` instance.

```
newtype CChar = CChar Char

instance Eq CChar where
  _ == _ = True

bad :: String -> Bool
bad path = getAny $ foldMap (coerce (isPrefixOf :: [CChar] -> [CChar] -> Bool)) ["src", "lib"] $ path
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured I'd point out one sometimes-convenient workaround. You basically want

```
isRoot :: String -> Bool
isRoot path = getAny $ foldMap (Any . isPrefixOf) ["src", "lib"] $ path
```

but want to coerce `isPrefixOf` rather than composing a function with it. In this situation, there's really no point, but if you have some unknown passed function instead of `isPrefixOf`, this can sometimes be important for performance. If you don't want to give a full type signature to `coerce`, or use type applications, one option is to replace the composition operator with a coercing one.

```
import Data.Profunctor.Unsafe ((#.))

isRoot :: String -> Bool
isRoot path = getAny $ foldMap (Any #. isPrefixOf) ["src", "lib"] $ path
```

The `Profunctor` instance for `->` defines `(#.)` something like

```
-- (#.) :: Coercible b c => q b c -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
_ #. f = coerce f
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I think of it.

You have a function `coerce isPrefixOf`, and via context that function is constrained to have type `String -> String -> Any`. `isPrefixOf` on its own has type `Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool`.

Clearly `coerce` needs to convert the `Bool` into an `Any` in the return value, but what about the arguments? Are we instantiating `isPrefixOf` to `[Char] -> [Char] -> Bool` and then coercing to `[Char] -> [Char] -> Any`? Or are we instantiating `isPrefixOf` to `[T] -> [T] -> Bool` (for some `T`) and then coercing `T` to `Char` as well as `Bool` to `Any`? We need to know the instantiation of `isPrefixOf` before we can say whether this is valid.<sup>1</sup>

If we were applying `isPrefixOf` directly<sup>2</sup> then the fact that we were processing a `String` would instantiate `isPrefixOf`'s type variable to `Char` and everything would work. But you never directly use `isPrefixOf`; you use `coerce isPrefixOf`. So those strings you're processing are not connected to the `a` in `isPrefixOf`'s type, they're connected to the resulting type of `coerce isPrefixOf`. That doesn't help us instantiate the type of `isPrefixOf` **before** `coerce` gets hold of it. That `a` could be anything that `coerce` could **translate** into `Char`, it is not forced to **be** `Char` by this context. Something else is needed to tell us that `a` must be `Char`.

That ambiguity is what GHC is complaining about. It's not that the compiler isn't clever enough to notice that the only possible choice for `isPrefixOf` is `[Char] -> [Char] -> Any`, rather the code you've written is actually missing a piece of information the compiler needs to (correctly) deduce that.

`coerce` utterly destroys type inference "through" it, because as far as type inference is concerned `coerce :: a -> b` (whether the `Coercible a b` constraint actually holds up to scrutiny is another matter). There are no constraints on what types `coerce` can "try" to convert between, only on what it can successfully convert, so no chains of unification can be drawn through `coerce`. You'll need to pin down the types of each side independently, if there are any type variables.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> And actually, there could be multiple valid ways to instantiate it that result in different behaviour for your final function. An obvious one would be `newtype CaseInsensitiveChar = C Char` where the `Eq` instance uses `toLower`; `isPrefixOf :: [CaseInsensitiveChar] -> [CaseInsensitiveChar] -> Bool` can **also** be coerced to `[Char] -> [Char] -> Any`, but has different behaviour than a coerced `isPrefixOf :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Bool`.

<sup>2</sup> Or rather, passing it to a `foldMap` which is applied to strings.

<sup>3</sup> By "side" I'm referring to the way `isPrefixOf` is on the "inside" of a `coerce` application, and everything else only interacts with the result of `coerce` and so is on the "outside".